# How to insert multiple rows based on a quantity value in one row?

Tags: mysql, loops, insert

In MySQL, I am converting a table from a single row per item type (a quantity of items) to a single row per item, so that additional detail can be stored about individual items.

Here is an example source table:

```
id    parent_id    qty    item_type
--    ---------    ---    ---------
1     10291        2      widget
2     10292        4      thinger
```

I want to create a new table with a new column containing info that cannot be applied to more than one item. Thus, the above table would end up as follows:

```
id    parent_id    item_type    info
--    ---------    ---------    ----
1     10291        widget       [NULL]
2     10291        widget       [NULL]
3     10292        thinger      [NULL]
4     10292        thinger      [NULL]
5     10292        thinger      [NULL]
6     10292        thinger      [NULL]
```

Is there a way I can iterate or loop each row of the source table, inserting a number of records equal to the source `qty` column? I would prefer to do this in sql instead of code to keep all of the conversion steps together (there are many others).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on other answers which provided some insight, I was able to find additional information ([by Kevin Bedell](http://www.kbedell.com/2009/03/02/a-simple-example-of-a-mysql-stored-procedure-that-uses-a-cursor/)) to create a stored procedure and use a cursor in a loop. I have simplified my solution so that it matches the example in my question:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS proc_item_import;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_item_import()
BEGIN
    # Declare variables to read records from the cursor
    DECLARE parent_id_val INT(10) UNSIGNED;
    DECLARE item_type_val INT(10) UNSIGNED;
    DECLARE quantity_val INT(3);

    # Declare variables for cursor and loop control
    DECLARE no_more_rows BOOLEAN;
    DECLARE item_qty INT DEFAULT 0;

    # Declare the cursor
    DECLARE item_cur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT
            i.parent_id, i.qty, i.item_type
        FROM items i;

    # Declare handlers for exceptions
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
    SET no_more_rows = TRUE;

    # Open the cursor and loop through results
    OPEN item_cur;

    input_loop: LOOP

        FETCH item_cur
        INTO parent_id_val, item_type_val, quantity_val;

        # Break out of the loop if there were no records or all have been processed
        IF no_more_rows THEN
            CLOSE item_cur;
            LEAVE input_loop;
        END IF;

        SET item_qty = 0;

        qty_loop: LOOP

            INSERT INTO items_new
                (parent_id, item_type)
            SELECT
                parent_id_val, item_type_val;

            SET item_qty = item_qty + 1;

            IF item_qty >= quantity_val THEN
                LEAVE qty_loop;
            END IF;

        END LOOP qty_loop;

    END LOOP input_loop;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Before asking this question, I had not used a stored procedures, cursors, or loops. That said, I have read and encountered them frequently on SE and elsewhere, and this was a good opportunity to learn

It may be worth noting that the example on Kevin's page (linked above) does not use  `END%%` (just `END`) which caused some headache in trying to get the script to work. When creating a procedure, it is necessary to change the delimiter temporarily so that semicolons terminate statements inside the procedure, but not the creation process of the procedure itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can do with stored procedure. That will be like below. Below is stored procedure I am using for inserting products into log based on their quantity.

Seem you have to do similar task. You can get how to use database cursor in stored procedure to loop over a result set in MySQL from below example.

```
   DELIMITER $$
     DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS CursorProc$$
     CREATE PROCEDURE CursorProc()
     BEGIN
     DECLARE  no_more_products, quantity_in_stock INT DEFAULT 0;
     DECLARE  prd_code VARCHAR(255);
                 DECLARE  cur_product CURSOR FOR 
     SELECT  productCode FROM products;
       DECLARE  CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND 
     SET  no_more_products = 1;

     /* for  loggging information */
     CREATE  TABLE infologs (
     Id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     Msg varchar(255) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (Id)
     );
     OPEN  cur_product;

     FETCH  cur_product INTO prd_code;
     REPEAT 
     SELECT  quantityInStock INTO quantity_in_stock
     FROM  products
     WHERE  productCode = prd_code;

     IF  quantity_in_stock < 100 THEN
     INSERT  INTO infologs(msg)
     VALUES  (prd_code);
     END  IF;
     FETCH  cur_product INTO prd_code;
     UNTIL  no_more_products = 1
     END REPEAT;
     CLOSE  cur_product;
     SELECT *  FROM infologs;
     DROP TABLE  infologs;
     END$$
     DELIMITER;
```

Seems your task is 90% same as above procedure. Just do needful changes. It will work.

Comment: Thanks for the example, this was helpful in arriving at a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create stored procedure, declare a cursor that reads source table and for each row inserts `qty` rows into destination table.

Answer (score 1):

That is just an example of code that I have here, it is not adapted to your needs, but it does exactly what you need, and it is simple than a procedure, or temporary table.

```
SELECT event, id, order_ref, storeitem_barcode_create(8), NOW()
FROM (
    SELECT mss.id, mss.event, mss.order_ref, mss.quantity, mss.product_id, 
    @rowID := IF(@lastProductID = mss.product_id AND @lastID = mss.id, @rowID + 1, 0) AS rowID, 
    @lastProductID := mss.product_id, 
    @lastID := mss.id
FROM module_barcode_generator mbg, 
(SELECT @rowID := 0, @lastProductID := 0, @lastID := 0) t
INNER JOIN module_events_store_sold mss ON mss.order_ref = "L18T2P"
) tbl
WHERE rowId < quantity;
```

Answer (score 0):

Typo in JYelton's solution for his/her own question:

FETCH item_cur
        INTO parent_id_val, item_type_val, quantity_val;

Should be:

FETCH item_cur
        INTO parent_id_val, quantity_val, item_type_val;

Otherwise very good.